# need php script to rewrite URL query string 

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have issue with a strange url request to my site.. that may come from bot or other website ..
 i have researched all my code and link on web.. but not find and link like that
the url they request not in correct order is:

```
/modules.php?file=article&name=News&sid=281737
```

but the correct one should be

```
/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=281737
```

in fact the php can handle both of those ... but i using static caching system , which makes two files on cache. Making lots of files is not good for web performance.

I need a php script that use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and regex to detect the wrong url
then send it to correct url with 301 header

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it at the web server level. Since you tagged your question `.htaccess` I'm assuming that's Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=(.*)&name=(.*)&sid=(.*)
RewriteRule modules.php modules.php?name=%2&file=%1&sid=%3 [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tested that, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this -

```
<?php

if (preg_match ('/file=article\&name=Name/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: ' . str_replace('file=article&name=Name', 'name=Name&file=article', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

or for a more generic one

```
<?php

if (preg_match ('/file=(.*)\&name=(.*)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: ' . preg_replace('/file=(.*)&name=([^&]*)/', 'file=${1}\&name=${2}', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
}
```